# ServiceStack.Redis client - A transaction is already in progress

Tags: c#, transactions, redis, servicestack

I'm using the `servicestack.redis` client to connect. Redis is basically being used as SignalR backplane (which uses the booksleeve client). I'm additionally using ServiceStack.Redis client to maintain a connection list

I have code like this in the `RedisConnectionManager.cs` (along with similar methods for `AddConnection` and `GetConnections`. The `AddConnection` and `RemoveConnection` are called by methods on the SignalR hub.

Now let's get into the issue... Once in a while, I get a `InvalidOperationException` with the message `A transaction is already in progress` in the `CreateTransaction` call. This is generally after an exception is thrown by Redis in the if statement `if (connections == null || connections.Count == 0)`.

Anyway, what happens is that after that, things no longer work until I restart the process - since everytime I get an `InvalidOperationException`. I poked into the ServiceStack.Redis client code and according to the docs, it should either commit or discard the transaction. Seems like that's not happening and then the client is in a limbo state since the `RedisClient.Transaction` object is never `null`ed.

I couldn't find a bug tracker for `ServiceStack.Redis` so hopefully folks on SO will know better.

```
    public void RemoveConnection(string clientId, string connectionId)
    {

        try
        {
            var key = "CONNECTION_" + clientId;
            redis.Watch(key);

            var connections = redisTypedClient.Lists[key];


            if (connections == null || connections.Count == 0)
            {
                return;
            }


            using (var t = redisTypedClient.CreateTransaction())
            {
                t.QueueCommand(c => c.RemoveItemFromList(connections, connectionId));
                t.Commit();
            }

        }
        finally
        {
            redis.UnWatch();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue in this case was that I was reusing the redis connection which wasn't a good idea. As soon as I moved to creating and using a new Redis connection each time, this issue went away.